# Different averages of 3 numbers

Tags: inequality, arithmetic, average

If three numbers $a,b,c\gt0$ have a geometric average of $30$ and if the numbers $ab$,$bc$ and $ca$ have an arithmetic average of $1130$, what is the harmonic average of $a$, $b$ and $c$?

For the geometric average I found that $a⋅b⋅c=30^3$ and $ab+bc+ca=3390$ for the arithmetic average... But then I'm stuck...

Comment: Do you know the definitions of those averages?

Comment: Yes I do, if you mean if I know how to calculate them...

Comment: Great, then you have some equations to work with; try to write them out and play around with them.

Comment: Yea for the geometric average I found that $a\cdot b\cdot c=30^3$. And $a+b+c=3390$... But them I'm stuck...

Comment: Okay, that's fair! Edit your question to include that (your efforts and where you are stuck), otherwise your question probably will get downvoted and closed (as off-topic).

Comment: Okay, is done :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The arithmetic mean referred to in the question is for the three numbers $ab,bc$ and $ca$, not $a,b,c.$ Then calculate $$\frac{ab+bc+ca}{abc}.$$

Comment: Well that's 3390/30^3... But in what does that help?

Comment: Do it with the symbols. Then you get $1/a+1/b+1/c$. Now look at the definition of the harmonic mean.

Comment: Ohh yea and the definition is n over that!!! So the answer would be 3/(3390/30^3)? Am I right?

Comment: Yep, that is correct! :)